# Is RDP override of redirected printer setting an issue with Server 2012 or printer driver?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services, network-printer

Windows 10 / 64-bit Pro workstations  connecting to Microsoft Server 2012 via Remote Desktop Connection are experiencing a problem with their redirected printer, a Lexmark Model XM5365. The Lexmark driver, as installed locally on the workstation, has been modified to produce single-sided printing by default (the factory default is two-sided printing). But when the printer is redirected via RDP, the factory default of two-sided printing is reimposed and cannot be changed except on a job-by-job basis.

Comment: In theory it should still work. If you want help add details about the printing defaults vs print preferences set.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I'm using the Lexmark PS driver installed directly on each workstation. The factory default is for 2-sided printing. That is changed (successfully) to 1-sided printing, and this remains in effect for all printing from the local session. But upon connecting to the Server 2012 via RDP, the factory default of 2-sided printing is reimposed. It cannot be changed during the RDP session except on a job-by-job basis. It drives the users nuts since their RDP work requires 1-sided output for clients.